# Change UIBarButtonItem Icon after pressed iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, button, uibarbuttonitem

In the `viewDidload` method, I've declared a button and set RightBarButton...

```
    let btnFavourite = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30))
    btnFavourite.addTarget(self, action: "btnFavourite:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    btnFavourite.setImage(UIImage(named: "star"), forState: .Normal)
    btnFavourite.setImage(UIImage(named: "star_filled"), forState: .Highlighted)
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnFavourite)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightButton], animated: true)
```

How do I pressed the button from image 'star.png' then change to 'star_filled.png'? and press the button from 'star_filled.png' to 'star.png'?

How to make two functions like

```
func btnFavourite()
{
    //clicked the favourite button then image change to star_filled.png
}

fun btnUnfavourite()
{
    //clicked the button then the bar button image change to star.png
}
```

Comment: you have your callback `btnFavourite` set up, have you tried changing the images in there?

Comment: the code you have should work fine actually highlighted state would change the image when you touch once and take off your hand, like hove action. What do you want to achieve be clear pal.

Comment: @luk2302 what to write in the btnFavourite function there in order to make the UIBarButtonItem icon change?

Comment: @satheeshwaran I want to make the icon change to another image, not only hover, so I cannot use the .Highlighted state in this case?

Comment: Apple doc for Highlighted state - "Highlighted state of a control. A control enters this state when a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up event. You can retrieve and set this value through the highlighted property.
Highlighted state of a control. A control enters this state when a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up event. You can retrieve and set this value through the highlighted property."

Comment: Try to use .Selected or do the image change in the button action as @luk2303 suggests.

Comment: @satheeshwaran I changed that, but no respond...is there anyway to make 2 functions for favourite and unfavorite for the bar button item?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create Method which will update you Button based on the state of `self.isFavourited`

```
var isFavourited = false;//declare this above the viewDidload()

func updateRighBarButton(isFavourite : Bool){
    let btnFavourite = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30))
    btnFavourite.addTarget(self, action: "btnFavouriteDidTap", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


    if isFavourite {
         btnFavourite.setImage(UIImage(named: "star_filled"), forState: .Normal)
    }else{
        btnFavourite.setImage(UIImage(named: "star"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnFavourite)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightButton], animated: true)
}



func btnFavouriteDidTap()
{
    //do your stuff
    self.isFavourited = !self.isFavourited;
    if self.isFavourited {
        self.favourite();
    }else{
        self.unfavourite();
    }
    self.updateRighBarButton(self.isFavourited);
}


func favourite()
{
    //do your favourite stuff/logic
}

func unfavourite(){
    //do your unfavourite logic
}
```

In the viewDidload method, call first time, i.e.

```
self.updateRighBarButton(self.isFavourited);//first time self.isFavourited will be false
```

Comment: then what if I want to Unfavorite it, where should I write the stuff for it?

Comment: @jefferyleo check edited answer as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank You! You have answer my question and fulfil my needs....thanks a lot dude...appreciate

Comment: This is really working. None of the other approaches didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it, but this is what worked for me:

In viewDidLoad():

```
    let share_button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))
    let fave_button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon-star"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(favorite))
    let faved_button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon-star-filled"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(unfavorite))
    if YOUROBJECT.faved{
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [share_button, faved_button]
    }
    else{
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [share_button, fave_button]
    }
```

Then create the two #selector functions:

```
@objc func favorite(){
    let share_button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))
    let faved_button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon-star-filled"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(unfavorite))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [share_button, faved_button]
    YOUROBJECT.faved = true
}
@objc func unfavorite(){
    let share_button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))
    let fave_button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon-star"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(favorite))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [share_button, fave_button]
    YOUROBJECT.faved = false
}
```