# UIBarButton position changes on icon change

Tags: iphone, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Here is the problem:
[image]

When user taps on the star icon its vertical position changes by 6 points (I've traced its frame). The reason is I'm using a custom font for the `UIBarButtonItem`:

`UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIView.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : universalSmallFont], for: .normal)`

But I don't know how to prevent this frame change. I have tried getting the button's frame before the image change and apply it again after changing image, but it did not work:

```
func setBarButtonImage(button: UIBarButtonItem, imageName: FontAwesome) {
        var _frame:CGRect?
        let barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!
        let buttonItemView = barButtonItem.value(forKey: "view")
        if let frame = (buttonItemView as? UIView)?.frame {
            _frame = frame
        }

        let icon = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: imageName, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

        button.image = icon
        if _frame != nil {
            (barButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView)?.frame = _frame!
        }
```

}

Comment: did you create custom bar button item?

Comment: No, it's the default one.

Comment: Can you please show the storyboard images ?

Comment: @BhupatBheda http://i.imgur.com/Zmr8oFB.png

Comment: Okay i find out something for you i hope it would be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542467/change-uibarbuttonitem-icon-after-pressed-ios-swift

Comment: @BhupatBheda Not is not related to my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143344/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-maysam).

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @SebastianRoth It was a font issue, I changed the font to solve it.

Comment: @Maysam - I also solved this yesterday by simply creating two bar button items (one for each state) and show/hide them accordingly. So I would never modify the image of the bar button itself.

Comment: @SebastianRoth I guess you can create a UIView and put your button on it, then you will have more freedom to change the position of the button.

Comment: Maybe - I usually try to stay away from putting custom UIViews in navigation bars.